# multilevel slices with string indexes

Tags: string, go, slice

I have a code that looks like this:

```
var c [][]string

c = append(c, d)
c = append(c, l)
```

Assuming that both d and l are []strings. This works, however it would return something like this:

[["0241025570","0241025571","1102182000"],["0241025570","0241025571","1102182000"]]

How would it be possible to structure it to look like this:

["d": ["0241025570","0241025571","1102182000"], "l":["0241025570","0241025571","1102182000"]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would like to have would no longer be a slice, but a map of slices. You can get the desired results using the following code:

```
c := make(map[string][]string)
c["d"] = d
c["l"] = l
```

Depending on your usage, you may want to [make copies](https://godoc.org/builtin#copy) of `d` and `l`, instead of using them directly in the map:

```
c := make(map[string][]string)
c["d"] = make([]string, len(d))
c["l"] = make([]string, len(l))
copy(c["d"], d)
copy(c["l"], l)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you clarify on what situations would requirement to make copies? All I am doing is building the map and using the JSON, nothing else.

Comment: @KNgu: you only need to copy your slices if you want a snapshot of your variables to be stored in the map (i.e. if you make changes to `d` or `l` after you add them to the map, you don't want the changes to be reflected in the map).